# DateTime equality and declaration leads to ContextSwitchDeadlock

Tags: c#, datetime, declaration

I think this one is silly question, but it was a bit strange for me to discover that i cant do the following:

```
EditingItem.FROM = EditingItem.TO = DateTime.Now;   // FROM, TO are DateTime
```

after this manipulations, the program *sometimes* hangs, but sometimes it just works as i thought it should.
Here is the exception:

> ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected Message: The CLR has been unable to
>   transition from COM context 0x478b80 to COM context 0x478dd0 for 60
>   seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is
>   most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long
>   running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation
>   generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the
>   application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating
>   continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded
>   apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as
>   CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long
>   running operations.

Changing the code to:

```
  EditingItem.FROM = DateTime.Now;
  EditingItem.TO = DateTime.Now;
```

helps in my situation.

Cant google the question properly, to see explanation, so can you help and explain why whis expression is wrong?
PS more discussion in comments.
Here are some results from experiments:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
EditingItem.FROM = EditingItem.TO = d;//hang
```

added loop for timing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
   i++;
}

DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
EditingItem.FROM = EditingItem.TO = d;//hang
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the datetime. If it hangs, some thread synchronisation happens which are not provided in the question.

Comment: @Aliostad, think you are right. Ive added exception. But if its related to threads-why it always hangs on this line?

Comment: Can you explain how COM is related to what seems like a `DateTime` question? What is the type of `EditingItem`?

Comment: @MartinLiversage, EditingItem is some database type, generated by entity framework provider. I dont use COM in my code..Tho i do use DevExpress components(WPF) and this initialization happens after i refresh their grid. May be there is something wrong with their grid, but for me the interesting part is WHY it hangs on THIS line and why separation of initializations helps??

Comment: @0x49D1: To troubleshoot this identify the two threads involved. One is the user interface thread, and that thread is being blocked in some way. Another background thread is trying to access your COM object (most likely the DevExpress component) while the user interface thread is blocked. There could be other scenarios, but this is a likely candidate. I still don't see the connection to the `DateTime` thing. Maybe it is just a random timing issue that triggers your problem. `DateTime.Now` is somewhat "slow" so introducing another call adds a slight delay.

Comment: @MartinLiversage, i though about timings, thats why i paused on a breakpoint near that line(to allow any another thread do their work), but still it hangs right after that initialization.

Comment: @MartinLiversage, thats why i dont think this one is some random timing issue.. :(

Comment: @MartinLiversage, ill try to add more code before that initialization to increase timings and write the result here.

Comment: @0x49D1: If you can debug your application then when it hangs break the debugger and inspect the stack trace of each thread. Try Debug -> Windows -> Parallel Stacks for a nice overview. You should be able to see what each thread is waiting for.

Comment: What happens if you just do: `EditingItem.FROM = EditingItem.TO`? Also, what about `EditingItem.FROM = EditingItem.TO.AddDays(-1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that there seems to be a `lock` happening - again code not provided so just a guess - where object is locked so that assigning a property from another property will deadlock on itself.

If you are dealing with COM, this can be maginfied by the fact that COM objects are Single-Threaded Apartment objects.

Comment: Seems like a nice short explanation to me. Tho there are NO other threads in MY code, also i dont use locks in that class.

Comment: @0x49D1: Locks will never deadlock unless at least two threads are involved. The exception also clearly identifies two COM contexts or apartments which each have at least one thread.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
var temp = DateTime.Now;
EditingItem.TO = temp;
EditingItem.FROM = temp;
```

Putting the assignments on a single line is just a shorthand that perhaps shows the C language roots of C#.

Now that you have provided more information about your problem it seems that your program hangs because of a COM deadlock. It is hard to see hov the assignment of `DateTime` values can force that deadlock. The exception is indicating that the CLR is trying to call a COM object in a STA (Single Threaded Apartment) that is not processing it's message pump.

I'm just trying to describe a possible scenario, but knowing about the specifics of your problem I may be way off:

Lets say that you have a COM based control in your user interface that is responding to an event (e.g. a click). In the event handler a background thread is started and the event handler then waits for that thread to complete or set a signal that the background task is complete. The background task (running on another thread) then tries to get a property on the COM object. This will trigger a deadlock like the one you are experiencing.

The background thread running in another apartment than the COM control has to marshal the call to the apartment of the COM control (a STA). This is done by sending a windows message to a hidden window used by COM. However, the thread that is supposed to dispatch that windows message is currently blocked waiting for the background thread to complete. The background thread is waiting for the user interface thread to dispatch windows message. This is a deadlock.

To avoid this never block the user interface thread, or if you have to at least make sure that you pump the message pump while you are waiting. How that is done is hinted at in the exception message.

Comment: :S sure, i know....Added the exception. Think the problem is not with my variable initialization.

Comment: This is **not correct** - it is correct only for filed or auto-property. This is not equivalent - there could be code underneath those properties and in this case . Deserves a -1 but I spared it.

Comment: @MartinLiversage, added some results after checks. If i write the code you provided- it works ok.